# Java sound | UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: java, exception, audio, javasound

Hääwuo,
I'm trying to implement Pong.

Now I want to play sound, but it throws an exception (UnsupportedAudioFileException).
What did I wrong?

```
AudioInputStream ainBalk;   
Clip clip;


//Constructor beginning
public Playboard() {
    try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        ainBalk = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Playboard.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Balk.wav")); // Exception!                      
} catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
    ...
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What was the message in the exception?

Comment: @greg-449  The entire stack trace might be handy here..

Comment: WAV should usually be supported... but what exact format is your WAV in?
Bits/channel, channels, sampling rate, ...
Also, did you double-check that your call to getResourceAsStream() actually returns a valid stream?

Answer (score 1):

From the Java doc:

> An UnsupportedAudioFileException is an exception indicating that an operation failed because a file did not contain valid data of a recognized file type and format.

[UnsupportedAudioFileException.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/UnsupportedAudioFileException.html)

Different audio software does sometimes produce very different and sometimes incompatible .wav files. So chances are, that the Java AudioSystem is not compatible to the specific wav file you want to open. You could try to convert the file to aiff or you can open the file in a different audio editor/converter and save it as a new file.

Comment: A good converter would be Audacity (free). One of the most common supported file formats: 16 bit encoding, 44100 fps, stereo, little-endian.